# Why is CSS not being loaded in my React Electron app?

Tags: reactjs, electron, react-bootstrap

I've set up an Electron app with React using the `electron-react-boilerplate` package, and then imported the `react-bootstrap` library with npm.

I edited the default the contents of App.tsx to test out the bootstrap components. Here is the code:

```
import { Alert, Col, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { MemoryRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const Hello = () => {

  console.log('hello there')
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Alert variant={'primary'}>
          This is a alert, check it out!
        </Alert>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col xs={2}>My First Column</Col>
        <Col xs={5}>My Second Xolumn!</Col>
        <Col xs={5}>My Last Column </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Hello />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

This is what my app looks like when it runs. As you can see, the content is there, but none of the bootstrap CSS is being loaded.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need install both `bootstrap` and `react-bootstrap`:

`npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap@5.1.3`

then import the `bootstrap.min.css` in `App.tsx`:

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

please refer to: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction